# Spring Boot 2.6.X + JRE 17 Openj9 - Unhandled exception Type=Segmentation error

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc, openj9

Target of this post is to help to solve the the problem in the title.

Infos:

**java -version**

```
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition 17.0.2.0 (build 17.0.2+8)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM 17.0.2.0 (build openj9-0.30.0, JRE 17 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20220128_115 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 9dccbe076
OMR      - dac962a28
JCL      - 64cd399ca28 based on jdk-17.0.2+8)
```

**SpringBoot version**: v2.6.2

**Detailed error**:

```
    Unhandled exception
    Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
    J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000018 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000001
    Handler1=00007FD4FEE86560 Handler2=00007FD4FEBE4BA0 InaccessibleAddress=00000000FFFFF780
    [...]
    Module=/opt/jre-17.0.2+8-openj9/lib/default/libj9vm29.so
```

Answer (score 1):

After much tries, I isolated the problem: it seems that the problem only occurs when the following dependency is active (maven syntax):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

where ${springdoc.version} is 1.6.3 (or <= 1.6.3)

Use dependency >= 1.6.4 and the problem is solved.